# Azure AKS Pods stuck in "ContainerCreating"or "Terminating" state

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I'm learning to create AKS pods, and seem to have broken something.

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                     READY     STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
mysql-6977c54cf5-z6xtw   0/1       ContainerCreating   0          12m
mysql-6977c54cf5-z97lm   0/1       Terminating         5          26m
```

If I look on the Azure portal, there are more containers listed as either "running"or "waiting"but I cannot see how to remove them either.

I know it's related to me deleting the persistent storage voume half-way through the pod coming up.  How do I go about removing them and starting a-fresh?

Comment: can you run "kubectl describe pod <podname>" to get more details on the error

Answer (score 1):

You can get AKS containers in the portal like this:
[image]

When you create AKS Cluster, it will create a resource group named **MC_ResourceGroupName_AKSClusterName** and the containers act as Azure VMs in the group.

You can use the kubectl command like this `kubectl scale kubectl scale --replicas=2 deployment/azure-vote-front` to scale the pods, even set the `replicas=0` and then scale back. It will create new pods.

As I test and the results here:
[image]